# verification of proof for uniform continuity for a function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, defined by $f(x,y) = 2x$ in a metric space

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, solution-verification, uniform-continuity

I am being asked to determine whether the function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, defined by $f(x,y) = 2x$ is uniformly continuous or not. In the question $\mathbb{R}^2$ is equipped with the "Manhattan" metric $d$ which is defined as $$d((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2))=|x_1-x_2|+|y_1-y_2|$$ and $\mathbb{R}$ is equipped with the normal Euclidean metric $e$ so $$e(f(x_1,y_1),f(x_2,y_2))=|f(x_1,y_1)-f(x_2,y_2)|=|2x_1-2x_2|$$

I've produced this proof and I was looking for it to be verified:

> Let $\epsilon>0$ and let $\alpha=\epsilon/3$. Then
> $$|x_1-x_2|+|y_1-y_2|<\alpha$$
> Now
> $$|2x_1-2x_2|=2|x_1-x_2|<3(|x_1-x_2|+|y_1-y_2|)<3\alpha=\epsilon$$ so
> $$d((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2))<\alpha \Rightarrow e(f(x_1,y_1),f(x_2,y_2))<\epsilon\;\;\;\;\; \forall (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$$ so $f$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

I understand delta is the conventional character to use where I've used alpha, however this appeared as epsilon when I typed this. I hope this formatting is okay and I've presented my answer with sufficient rigour.

Comment: It looks generally fine. However, this strict inequality $2 |x_1 - x_2| < 3 (|x_1 - x_2| + |y_1 - y_2|)$ is not necessarily true (consider the case where $x_1 = x_2$ and $y_1 = y_2$). This doesn't affect your conclusions because $3 d ((x_1, x_2), (y_1, y_2)) < 3 \delta$ *is* strict. Also note that you could take $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{2}$.

Comment: Yes I had thought it seemed slightly imperfect and the choice of $\delta=\epsilon/2$ would be more tidy after I had completed it. Would the strict inequality be the only place where marks could potentially be lost? Other than that does it look accurate and sufficient for the conclusion "f is uniformly continuous on $\Re^2$"?

Comment: Yes, your proof correctly shows that $f$ is uniformly continuous. As a matter of clarity, you could begin your proof as "Let $\epsilon > 0$ and $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{3}$. *Assume* $d ((x_1, x_2), (y_1, y_2)) < \delta$, then..." The fact that the distance between two points in the domain is less than $\delta$ is not a consequence of anything - you assume it to prove uniform continuity.

Comment: To denote the real numbers use $\mathbb R$ `\mathbb{R}` not $\Re$.